# CodePlex Sitemap Editor,Ribbon Editor solutions are not working with CRM 2011 rollup 12

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, codeplex

[CodePlex](http://sitemapeditor.codeplex.com/) Site map editor is not working with CRM 2011 RU 12.
If someone has found any solution please let me know.

When I am trying to import the solution it's saying this version is not supported which is RU 12.
Previously I was able to use this with CRM 2011 RU 7.

I have Same issue for [**Ribbon Editor for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011**](http://ribboneditor.codeplex.com/)

[image]

Comment: try to use the one inside http://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: How do you know its not working?

Comment: i cannot upload the solution to my CRM organization which has rollup 12. previously i was able to work with which was user RU 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Tool is the best one to Edit ribbon for this.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmmusings/archive/2012/09/12/crm-2011-ribbon-workbench-getting-guids-from-selected-records-in-the-grid.aspx#.UeZA-o3WWzQ

It is working with RU 12

Answer (score 0):

Sitemap Editor and Ribbon Editor for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 are windows applications, they are not CRM 2011 solutions.

Just extract the zip file to a folder, launch the executable, configure the connection and you will be able to edit the sitemap (or the ribbon).